# Embedded Jetty to test the spring application startup

Tags: spring, junit, jetty, embedded-jetty

What I am trying to do is, to have a test to startup the whole application to see if there's any error. But I want to use the applicationContext.xml from the /src/resource folder and not form test/resource. How can I do that in JUnit?

My application is big and a lot of people share the same codebase. So, I just wanted to have a quick test to see if the checkin can start up the application.

This is my simple code but it looks like it's missing some of the autowire stuff, that's why I want to use the xml files from /src/resource, so I don't have to maintain two locations.

My application is plain Spring MVC 3.0

```
@Test(enabled = false)
public void shouldStartupTheApp() throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server();
    SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(9999);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {connector});

    Context context = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);

    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml");

    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet);
    context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
    server.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your src/resources/filename.xml in other xml-file using

```
<import resource="classpath:/filename.xml" />
```

Comment: so I can have applicationContext in test/resource but imports everything from src/resource?

Comment: @toy yes, or you can create separate file in src/reouurce and includ it in both contexts